# SSMS 2014 - Failed to retrieve data for this request - unknown property IsMemoryOptimized

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2014

I get the following error when I try to expand keys for a table using SSMS 2014 on Azure SQL Server (13.0.702). If I use "Script Table as" I can get a working query. Has anyone else experienced this?

Error:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

unknown property IsMemoryOptimized (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
```

Information from SSMS:

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                       12.0.2000.8
- Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                     12.0.2000.8
- Microsoft Data Access
  Components (MDAC)                        10.0.10240.16384
- Microsoft MSXML                      3.0 6.0
- Microsoft Internet Explorer                      9.11.10240.16384
- Microsoft .NET    Framework                      4.0.30319.42000
- Operating System                     6.3.10240

Comment: You a using `SSMS 2014` for connection with previous version of `SQL Server`?

Comment: I'm using Azure SQL Server (13.0.702) with SSMS 2014. Will try with the latest version of SSMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the newest version of SSMS, currently Community Technology Preview 3 (CTP3) and now everything works. Link to latest SSMS:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt238290.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to download the lastest cumulative update to SQL Server from http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com.es/

Comment: I'm using Azure SQL Server but I will try to use SSMS CTP version.